# I can't debug in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I know this is a very common problem, but I tried a lot of stuff, I no one give me a solution. I have a program in C++ with C::B, and I cannot debug. I have the tick in the "-g" option at the "Build Options" in my project. And I have the "gdb.exe" as debugger. But the result is this:

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Build succeeded
Selecting target: 
Release
Adding source dir: I:\Juego para practicar\
Adding source dir: I:\Juego para practicar\
Adding file: bin\Release\Juego para practicar.exe
Starting debugger: 
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
**(no debugging symbols found)...(gdb)**
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb 5.2.1
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Program exited with code 030000000472.
Debugger finished with status 0
```

What can I do? I proved everything, but it remains with no debugging.

Comment: can you give an example code ?

Comment: **(no debugging symbols found)...(gdb)** - debug informations are not there in your exe

Answer (score 1):

"..
Selecting target: 
Release
.."

You are in release build, try to rebuild in debug

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Paste your buildlog showing us that you are getting the correct compiler flags.
For example, you should have -g for producing symbols.. You shouldn't have -s (strip) which removes all symbols not needed for relocations, etc.